# In Propel, can I select fields to return after save()

Tags: php, zend-framework, orm, propel

I create a new comment object and save it

```
$comment = new Comment();
$comment->setText('this is a comment');
$comment->setIp($ip);
$comment->save();
```

When I do a `var_dump($comment)`, I see that the object has a lot of detail that I don't want to pass to the view in MVC architecture. This means that I have to do extra filtering in the view.

So is there a way, right after save() to select only the fields that I will later want to pass to the view? Something like this code, so that the $comment object now has only the `text` field

```
$comment->save();
$comment->select(array('text'));
```

Comment: Why don't you want to pass the object to the view? Are you afraid you'll get so drunk that you'll try to change the object?

Comment: @Dan Grossman `ObjectQuery::create()` let you do a `->select()` to return only the columns you want. I'm trying to do the same thing for the new objects I create for consistency and code reuse reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd just pass the object... But if you want to have the columns in array you can either use toArray() or getByName() methods.

Having only some columns in an ORM object doesn't make sense to me.

You have your question tagged as both Doctrine and Propel - this answer is for Propel.